# My conection on sql server Azure not work well

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core

I create and test this connection on VS Studio 2015 community and get success result.

But when I start my application I get this error

> SqlException: Login failed for user 'user'.

see my conetion string on `appsettings.json`

```
"ConnectionStrings": 
 {
   "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=precadastro201665654;User ID=user;Password=***********"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved My problem when I copy the connection string on azure, putting my user and id without "{}" and past it in my appsettings.json